# Underscores are escaped with backslashes in Docstrings when writing Python in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I try to document my code, and specify variables that contain underscores, they aren't displayed properly.
Example code:

```
def printl(tex_t):
"""
    Clears the console and prints whatever text is inputed, under a heading.

    Parameters
    ----------
        tex_t (String) : The text you want to print.

    Returns
    -------
        Nothing
"""
# Code goes here
```

But I get this:
[image]

I'm using Python 3.8.6 64-bit, and the VSCode Python extension v2020.9.114305

EDIT:
So I messed around with the Python.languageserver settings, and it looks like only Microsoft and Pylence have this issue. Switching this to Jedi fixes the problem.

Comment: Feels like a very specific bug. Try to open an issue on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues)

Comment: I use Pylance and only get this in the tooltip for the completion provider (the text after the \ is also red and I have a `-> None` in the header. But the arguments tooltip when I enter the `(` is correct.

Comment: the doc strings are interpreted as Markdown, remove the `-----` lines and you get different behavior. In Markdown `_` signals italic but we want a literal `_` so it gets escaped but the renderer of the tooltip does not understand character escaping. But the Markdown translator should not escape the `_`

Comment: @rioV8 Did you resolve the issue? And if yes, what was the problem?

Comment: @PriNova I did not had this problem, I never use doc strings, I just experimented with the given example and found cases of different behavior, I have no clue where in VSC or Python language server this conversion to Markdown is done, It looks like another Language sever has different behavior