# How to auto wrap the VSCode python intelliSence provided by Pylance?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, word-wrap

PyLance response:

> Not converting to markdown wouldn't be a good idea (as it prevents us from using markdown at all in the tooltips). VS Code's plaintext support is broken until 1.52, but maybe then we could add a toggle to say "use plaintext only".

---

I'm using VSCode to write python, and using Pylance to provide intelliSence. I wonder if it can provide auto wrapped information in a neat way? The intellisense information currently provided mixed all things in a single line which makes it hard to see.

More specifically, the figure below shows the intellisense without auto wrap. I would like the `Args:` and the following information shows exactly as the green comment writes (each line is one parameter with its explanation). How can I achieve it?

figure 1: intellisense of a user defined class `FDNN` without auto wrap

[image]

figure 2: intellisense of a pytorch class `nn.Linear` without auto wrap

[image]

---

**EDIT 1:**

removing the `r` before comment doesn't work

[image]

---

**EDIT 2:**

adding `-` renders better than plain text, but face with `_` escape problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: **Remove the `r` in front of your docstring**

---

**Edit**

I have tried the `r` with a doc string for a function but I can't reproduce the behavior.

If you format the doc string as a kind of Markdown it will display better only it has [problems with `_` in variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64551613/underscores-are-escaped-with-backslashes-in-docstrings-when-writing-python-in-vi).

Underline header lines with `-` (minus) and the text is rendered reasonable.

```
class FDNN:
  """
  Applies a fused fuzzy .....

  Args
  ----
      input_size:     size of input vector
      memfcn:         type of membership functions
      memparalist:    list of tuples of membership functions
  """
  def __init__(self):
    pass
```

For functions the rendering of the doc string after you type the opening `(` is different, it is used as literal text in the arguments tooltip.

This might be a reason to create an issue for VSC. The descriptions in the different Providers are interpreted differently and should be possible to mark them as plain text or "Markdown"

Comment: thanks for your edited answer. I tried the `-` minus method and it worked more reasonable than plain text. But I also faced with `_` problems in variable names as you have mentioned. Since I can add `-` in my user defined functions or classes, I cannot edit comments in 3rd party packages like PyTorch, whose comments are shown in the images above and are rendered as plain text by Pylance. I agree that it might be a reason to create an issue for VSC. or is it related to interpreters (pylance, etc)?

Comment: @abmin Doc strings should be rendered AS IS. No markup interpretation. If the author makes an effort to format the string it look good. If you create a VSC issue and it is python specific they will let you know.

Comment: thanks. I've raised a issue for pylance, and here is the response: "Not converting to markdown wouldn't be a good idea (as it prevents us from using markdown at all in the tooltips). VS Code's plaintext support is broken until 1.52, but maybe then we could add a toggle to say "use plaintext only"."

Comment: @abmin No it will not prevent them to use Markdown. If they wrap doc strings with literal text Markdown before passing it to the tooltip rendering.